# Delete record from MongoDB collection, if record is more then 100,000 without using $skip, $limit and no pagination logic?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to delete the alert ( if alertstatus is in false ) and event based on the limit(100,000).

**Alert model**

```
    {
      "alertstartdatetime": 1708419600000,
      "alertplantstartdatetime": 1708439400000,
      "alertseverity": 4,
      "alertstatus": false | true,
      "_id": "65d46a1527231cf87646c27b2ae",
      "blockname": "IS1",
      "devicename": "Inverter 1",
      "alertdescription": "INVU DOWN",
      "plantname": "test",
      "plantid": "62fa0fb4930987607357a4352194d"
    }
```

**Event Model**

```
    {
      "_id": "65d467fe223456789009876543",
      "plantid": "6308733a815ab8545672075c1b35",
      "blockid": "631820677b654b08c3kiuytre653b3e",
      "deviceid": "631872f38efc5ac3d0e49876544666",
      "devicetypeid": 3,
      "blockdisplayname": "Block3",
      "devicedisplayname": "IC3 Inverter 2",
      "notificationid": "6579599283db91fc878c7885ac",
      "eventid": "6579599283db91fc8c7885ac",
      "eventdescription": "Running Status (MPPT)",
      "eventseverity": 3,
      "eventstatus": true,
      "eventdatetime": 1708419060000,
      "eventplantdatetime": 1708438860000,
      "ismanual": false,
      "eventcomments": [],
      "blockname": "ICR3",
      "devicename": "Inverter 2",
      "plantname": "test"
    }
```

I try to use $skip but for 100,000 record query will take so much time with huge data

```
const alertRecordLimit = 100000
await AlertDataModel(clientConnection).deleteMany({_id: {$nin: (await AlertDataModel(clientConnection).find({}, {_id:1}).skip(alertRecordLimit).lean())?.map((alert)=> alert?._id)}})

await EventDataModel(clientConnection).deleteMany({_id: {$in: (await EventDataModel(clientConnection).find({}, {_id:1}).skip(eventRecordLimit).lean())?.map((event)=> event?._id)}})
```

I tried the above MongoDB query.

But I am expecting this query should run fast and tried to delete the record from the collection with data also..

Answer (score 0):

To improve the efficiency of your queries, especially when dealing with large datasets, you can consider using indexes to speed up the lookup operations.
Ensure that you have appropriate indexes on the fields you are using in your queries.

For the AlertDataModel, you can create an index on the alert status field:

```
await AlertDataModel(clientConnection).createIndex({ alertstatus: 1 });
```

For the EventDataModel, create an index on the eventstatus field:

```
await EventDataModel(clientConnection).createIndex({ eventstatus: 1 });
```

Now that you have created indexes you can delete them much faster.

```
const alertRecordLimit = 100000;
await AlertDataModel(clientConnection).deleteMany({ alertstatus: false }, 
{ limit: alertRecordLimit });

const eventRecordLimit = 100000;
await EventDataModel(clientConnection).deleteMany({ eventstatus: false }, 
 { limit: eventRecordLimit });
```